# java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream

Tags: java, jackson, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am making a HTTPPost call using Apache HTTP Client and then I am trying to create an object from the response using Jackson.
Here is my code:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ReportingAPICall.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public void makePublisherApiCall(String jsonRequest)
{
    String url = ReaderUtility.readPropertyFile().getProperty("hosturl");
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonRequest);
        postRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        log.info("pub id :"+ExcelReader.publisherId);
        postRequest.addHeader("accountId", ExcelReader.publisherId);
        postRequest.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse postResponse = client.execute(postRequest);
        log.info(EntityUtils.toString(postResponse.getEntity()));

    //  Response<PublisherReportResponse> response = mapper.readValue(postResponse.getEntity().getContent(), Response.class);
    //  log.info("Reponse "+response.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        log.error(ex);
        Assert.assertTrue(false, "Exception : UnsupportedEncodingException");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        log.error(ex);
        Assert.assertTrue(false, "Exception : ClientProtocolException");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        log.error(ex);
        Assert.assertTrue(false, "Exception : IOException");
    }
```

Method makePublisherApiCall() will be called in a loop which runs for say 100 times.
Basically problem occurs when I uncomment the line:

```
//  Response<PublisherReportResponse> response = mapper.readValue(postResponse.getEntity().getContent(), Response.class);
//  log.info("Reponse "+response.toString());
```

After uncommenting I am getting exception:

```
Attempted read from closed stream.
17:26:59,384 ERROR com.inmobi.reporting.automation.reportingmanager.ReportingAPICall - java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
```

Otherwise it works fine.
Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What does `EntityUtils.toString(postResponse.getEntity())` do with the response entity? I would suspect, that it is consuming the entity's content stream. The [HttpClient javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29) states, that only entities, which are repeatable can be consumed more than once. Therefore if the entity is not repeatable you cannot feed the content stream to the mapper again. To avoid this you should only let the mapper consume the stream - if logging of content is required, log the parsed Response object.

Comment: But i thought this 2 lines are causing problem.                               //  Response<PublisherReportResponse> response = mapper.readValue(postResponse.getEntity().getContent(), Response.class);
//  log.info("Reponse "+response.toString());                          As after commenting these program works fine.

Comment: Yeah sure. If I am correct, the problem is that you can only **once** consume the content of the entity. I suspect that you are doing it twice through the logging and then the parsing. If you would like to check whether my suspicion is correct, comment out `log.info(EntityUtils.toString(postResponse.getEntity()));` and uncomment the following two lines, then check again if it works.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. Make sure you aren't consuming the entity's content stream in the "watch" or "inspect" section of your IDE. It's closed after it's consumed (read).

And sorry for my english.

Comment: This was causing issue for me and was wondering why it was throwing this exception even at first time-consuming. Then I realized that I had added "httpResponse.getEntity()" in my variable watch. Thanks for the answer. This saved my lot of time.

Answer (score 15):

I found an answer for similar issue with Spring RestTemplate here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor

if we want our interceptor to function as a request/response logger, then we need to read it twice – the first time by the interceptor and the second time by the client.
The default implementation allows us to read the response stream only once. To cater such specific scenarios, Spring provides a special class called BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory. As the name suggests, this class will buffer the request/response in JVM memory for multiple usage.

Here's how the RestTemplate object is initialized using BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory  to enable the request/response stream caching:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate( new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory( new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

The idea is that if you consume the postResponse, then you should put it in a variable in order to use it again in different places.
Else, the connection is closed and you can no longer consume the same response again.

I used to log it (for debug purposes) and always fails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was related to another reason,
I am getting this issue because I haven't use

`closeableresponce=client.Getmethod(FinalUrl);`

In my first Test1, it was mention but when I missed out in Test2, I forget to put this code that's why stream closed message shows...

```
public void getapiwithheader() throws ParseException, IOException
{
    client = new RestClient();
    closeableresponce=client.Getmethod(FinalUrl);

    HashMap<String, String> headermap = new HashMap<>();
    headermap.put("content-type", "application/json");
    //****************************************************************************    
    //Status code
    //****************************************************************************      
    int statuscode =closeableresponce.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("Status code "+statuscode);
    Assert.assertEquals(statuscode,RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE_200, "Status code is not 200");


    //****************************************************************************  
    // Json String
    //****************************************************************************      
    String responsestring=  EntityUtils.toString(closeableresponce.getEntity(),"UTF-8");
    JSONObject respjsonobj = new JSONObject(responsestring);
    System.out.println("Respose Json API"+respjsonobj);

    //****************************************************************************      
    // Verify the value of the JSON
    //****************************************************************************      
    String Email =TestUtil.getValueByJPath(respjsonobj,"/email");
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println("Print the value of Email "+Email);
    Assert.assertEquals(Email, "johndoe@google.com");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.

In my case, I need to get the response content via AOP/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd be much better if you elaborate your answer *I need to get the response content via AOP/* further with more details. Also note that you're answering an old and already answered question (answer with the green check-mark) while your current answer is more a comment than an answer. (Stack Overflow's Q/A format isn't intended for forum-style discussions). – Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works.