# Apache http write response to file

Tags: java, file, http, response, inputstream

I am trying to write org.apache.http.HttpResponse to file.

```
System.out.println("length");
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()).length);
```

gives this: 
length
48905367

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/response.json"));
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

gives this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:999)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the answer, but you need set the response info to new class first. I use Gson library:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HttpResponse response = httpGetRequest("URL_ENDPOINT");
    ResponseDTO responseDTO = gson.fromJson(prettyJsonResponse(response), 
    ResponseDTO.class);
```

This is the http get request method:

```
    private HttpResponse httpGetRequest(String url) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    return client.execute(request);
}
```

This is the maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

prettyJsonResponse method:

```
    private String prettyJsonResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException{
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }   
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone else has answered your question on another forum:
[java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636046/java-io-ioexception-attempted-read-from-closed-stream)

I had the same issue; I was calling `response.getEntity()` twice for the same content.  Once I commented out the second call, everything started working great.

Here is a link to the documentation: 
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29