# java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream. on AWS s3 getObject

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get object content from AWS s3 similar to mentioned here

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=471149

even after trying to solution mentioned about, i keep getting exception.

below is the scala code

```
val s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key))
try {
  val objectContent = s3Object.getObjectContent
  Some(new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(objectContent)))
} catch {
  case e : Exception => {
    val logMessage = "ContentFetchingException, key=" + key
    logError(logMessage, e)
    None
  }
} finally {
  if (s3Object != null) {
    s3Object.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: @ketan it's in the question title

Comment: @amit-kumar what exactly do you want to do with that object? If you just want to get all content, you can do it simpler. If the problem is with the stream, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/18636046/736957

Comment: Actually code has problem, when i say s3Object.close, i can not use GZipuInputStream since wrapping object is already closed.