# Karate ApacheHttpClient Response is failing with error com.intuit.karate - Runtimejava.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream

Tags: rest, httpresponse, karate

Reference: [java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636046/java-io-ioexception-attempted-read-from-closed-stream)

Reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/ApacheHttpClient.java

KarateCore - class file: ApacheHttpClient.java is unable to process the Response its failing at the code line

```
CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse;
byte [] bytes;
try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(requestBuilder.build());
            HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (responseEntity == null || responseEntity.getContent() == null) {
                bytes = Constants.ZERO_BYTES;
            } else {
                **InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent();**
                bytes = FileUtils.toBytes(is);
            }
            request.setEndTimeMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof ClientProtocolException && e.getCause() != null) { // better error message                
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

The Code is failing at line InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent(); when trying to read from a closed stream. The exception message displayed
**Error com.intuit.karate - Runtimejava.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.**

May be the InputStream need to updated.

I am able read the Http Response content using below code

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader((httpResponse.getEntity().getContent())));
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null){
      output = br,readLine();
      System.out.println(output);
}
```

Also the able to read the response using EntityUtils as a string content

```
String content = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
System.out.println(content);
```

Not sure if i am missing something in the feature:scenario file response or the ApacheHttpClient.java file need to updated to read InputStream and then convert to bytes.

```
Feature: Hello
Scenario: Rest API Post
Given url 'some url path'
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
And request { username: 'abc', password: 'pwd' }
When method POST
Then status 200
And print 'Response is:', response
```

The expected Response is a JSON format as:

```
{
  "accessToken": "akjdoioikf",
  "expires":"2020-01-29T01:09:48Z"
}
```

Any suggestions, appreciated!

Comment: I have only one suggestion. please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and please note that no one has ever reported this issue before